# How to Test if file contains full path or just file name, Python?

Tags: python

I have a script that I run from a GUI. The GUI is run in ArcGIS and basically, the first parameter can accept a file already embedded in ArcMap or I can use a explorer dialogue to navigate to the file locations.

If I use the option to choose the embedded file, then it only returns the file name:

> i.e. 'SOIL_LINES'

If I use the navigation option, then it returns the file name and it's fill path:

> C:\SOIL\SOIL_LINES.shp

I would like to test the input parameter to see if the file is just the file name or if it also includes the full path. I eventually need to parse out the path in option 2 to isolate the file name itself. That part I have figured out already.

I've used `os.path.isfile` but that will return the file in both scenarios because they are both considered a file.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to `isabs()` mentioned in another answer to test if it is a full path, you can use `os.path.basename()` and `os.path.dirname()` to find just the filename or just the directory path. No need to parse them out yourself.

There's lots of cool stuff in that library. I recommend reading the full documentation on it-- it's not long. http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. This pointed me in the right direction and I've managed to complete the test :)

Answer (score 4):

You could probably use [`os.path.isabs`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isabs) for this ...